# Modify a view in RCP

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In eclipse have a function that when I'm modifying a class that will implements a `*` in the title like this: [image]

And when I select Save button that `*` is no more.

The question is I want add that function into my application but have no idea or any key word to search it on google. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [IEditorPart](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIEditorPart.html) interface in your own editor and override its [isDirty()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ISaveablePart.html#isDirty()) and [doSave()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ISaveablePart.html#doSave(org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)) methods. Send notifications about content changes to workbench with [firePropertyChange()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/WorkbenchPart.html#firePropertyChange(int)) (with [PROP_DIRTY](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart.html#PROP_DIRTY) argument).
Don't forget to contribute your editor to org.eclipse.ui.editors extension point.

Comment: Could I ask a question? Can the `doSave()` methods contact with `SAVE` action in `ActionFactory`?

Comment: They automatically are. Do you use actions? Ensure you don't retarget save command, and default implementation should be enough for you.